# doing a python code and am in need of help in setting up conditions for a string

Tags: python, string

Basically I'm doing a python code in which a full date is input as a string in the format DD-YY-MM and then the day, month and year is output separately.
I need to validate the date which is input so the following conditions are met:

1. the date is not below 1 or over 31
2. the month is in the range of 1 to 12
3. the year is not less than 1900

```py
FullDate=input("enter todays date")

D=FullDate[0:2]
M=FullDate[3:5]
Y=FullDate[6:10]

if D>31 and D<1:
    print ("invalid date")
else:
    print("the date is",D)

if M<1 and M>12:
    print("invalid month")
else:
    print("the date is",M)

if Y<1990:
    print ("invalid year")
else:
    print("the year is",Y)
```

This is what I have tried but since the date is input as a string I cannot use > and < in if conditions and when I do I get the error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

how do I set up these conditions while also having the input as a string?

Comment: Please update your question with your code you have tried.

Comment: you can convert a string to number with `int()` and then compare. BTW a number is never going to be greater than 31 ***and*** less than 1.

Comment: @quamrana sorry, i have updated it now with the code

Comment: It looks like `D`, `M` and `Y` are all strings. Did you mean to convert them to integers before the comparisons? You can do: `D = int(FullDate[0:2])` etc. Also, this way, `FullDate` will remain a string.

Comment: @quamrana i tried that but now im getting another error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Well, you will have to check that the input really is `10` characters long, otherwise your slicing might produce empty strings. But, anyway, that wasn't your question. I think that has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitly cast your string into an int :

```
import sys
FullDate=input("enter todays date")
D=FullDate[0:2]
M=FullDate[3:5]
Y=FullDate[6:10]

if int(D)>31 or int(D)<1:
    sys.exit("invalid day")
else:
    print("the day is",D)

if int(M)<1 or int(M)>12:
    sys.exit("invalid month")
else:
    print("the month is",M)

if int(Y)<1990:
    sys.exit("invalid year")
else:
    print("the year is",Y)
```

Comment: the input needs to be a string because its input in the format DD-YY-MM, the input cannot be in that form if its an integer, i am asking how do i do it while keeping the input as a string

Comment: I don't understand, doing so won't change the variable year

Comment: I edited to use your code, also changed the ands into ors, this should be what you want

Comment: Glad to help, also if you're a beginner it would be a good idea to look at parsing functions such as strip() or split() for more flexible code